# I need to change font-family on whole site, instead of one page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

I'm making a site where you can read some text. In one page the text itself. In other - settings. And I need to change font-family and other options in text page. But when I redirect there (/settings -> /text) all changings are skipping. What should I do to fix it?

```
/* In settings.ejs */

<span id="fontFamily">
  <i id="fontCh" class="fas fa-font"></i> 
  <p id="fontWord"> Шрифт</p>
</span>

/* In read.ejs */

<pre id="text"><%= text %></pre>


fonts = [
    'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
    '"Times New Roman", Times, serif',
    '"Courier New", Courier, monospace',
    'monospace',
];

var i = 0;
document.getElementById('fontCh').addEventListener('click', () => {
    i++;
    if (i == fonts.length)
        i = 0;
});

var font = fonts[i];

document.getElementById('text').style.fontFamily = font;
```

Above is what i've tried.

UPD I think we all don't understand each other correctly. I know how to use external css file. But I need to know how to change property font-family with javaScript and what's most important - to be sure that it will not skip my changing when redirect to other page(what it does now)

Comment: @LeeTaylor of course and I wrote the default font-family for element, and the problem is that font doesn't changing as must, but stays default.

Comment: No, I mean a css file. This will allow you to change the look of your entire site from one place.

Comment: @LeeTaylor you mean document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily = font;? Or what? I don't really got you.

Comment: Hello @Lee Taylor , are you saying about the external type of CSS? I also think that that will be easy.

Comment: Yes, an external css file. What you are doing is not css in the strictest sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why are you using javascript to change your style?

Comment: @LeeTaylor  I'm doing settings, therefore I need js(if not - write me. I'm a beginner:). You can see it in my code above. If someone clicks on element, JavaScript is changing font-family on other and then changes it in needed element

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Vyacheslav Siniy , You can use an external CSS, for that you can add one file named 'style' or whatever you want with an extension .css like style.css. In head tag add that file path,

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

Use your code for the font in that CSS file and call this file in every page where you want. I think that will be easy.

Comment: Thanks for respond. It's a little bit different question. If i'm doing everything right, I have an element, in occasion of clicking on it font-family should change. But how can i change it in the separated css file instead of change it by document.getEl... ? Or other ways. What I need is to save css style and be sure that it will not change or skip when i redirect on other page. P.S. I think i may not explain very well, so if it's not clear, please say it:)

Comment: @VyacheslavSiniy , you want to change and save the CSS code file?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the approach of @Sandeep. Use an external stylesheet. Practice a bit here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

And this is the link to the stylesheet: [external stylesheet](https://www.w3schools.com/css/mystyle.css)

Answer (score 0):

Open the CSS file that is used on all pages of the website and add the following lines in CSS

```
body, body *{
   font-family: 'Arial' !important;
}
```

Replace Arial with your font name. This will implement font family on the entire website.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you merely want to change the font when you click on another element.

As such, you had a problem with your original code. The item to click had nothing there, so there was nothing to click with the mouse.

Also, your javascript was updating the font index but the code to change the font was outside the handler.

```js
fonts = [
    'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
    '"Times New Roman", Times, serif',
    '"Courier New", Courier, monospace',
    'monospace',
];
var i = 0;
document.getElementById('fontCh').addEventListener('click', () => 
{
  i++;
    if (i == fonts.length)
        i = 0;

  var font = fonts[i];

  document.getElementById('text').style.fontFamily = font;
});
```

```html
<span id="fontFamily">
  <i id="fontCh" class="fas fa-font">Click here to change font</i> 
  <p id="fontWord"> Шрифт</p>
</span>

<pre id="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</pre>
```

```
var fonts = [
    'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
    '"Times New Roman", Times, serif',
    '"Courier New", Courier, monospace',
    'monospace',
];
```

EDIT

Change your javascript file to:

```
// The following code will only execute when the page has loaded and is ready.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    var i = 0;
    document.getElementById('fontCh').addEventListener('click', () => 
    {
        document.getElementById('textplace').style.fontFamily = fonts[i];
        i++;
        if (i == fonts.length)
            i = 0;
    });

}, false);
```

Your index file should look like this below. You were referencing your files in the wrong way.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css" media="all">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <span id="read" onclick="onReadClick()"><i class="fas fa-book-open" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <span id="upload" onclick="onUploadClick()"><i class="fas fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <span><i class="fas fa-upload" id="fontCh" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <span id="cogs" onclick="onCogsClick()"><i class="fas fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>

    <main id="main">
        <div id="for_reading">
            <h2>Читай <i class="fas fa-book-open" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
            <div id="textplace" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <p id="content"> ADD YOUR CONTENT HERE</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="for_uploading">
            <h2>Загрузи <i class="fas fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
            <p>Загрузи, что хочешь, и читай на здоровье.</p>
            <form action="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" onchange="fileAdded()">
                <label for="file">
                    <i class="fas fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span id="output">Выбери файл.</span>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="for_settings">

        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="public/js/javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You have a few other issues. You have code referring to colours (wheat/white etc) and a file uploader that doesn't work. You are far better to get one thing working then move on to the next.

Comment: I made as you told but still :( I think that is problem - i have path to js in script tags in both ejs files, but call it only from one - settings.ejs. As I understood document.getElementById('text')... just can't reach this id because it placed in the other "document" - read.ejs. Therefore it doesn't change anything. Here is my entire project - https://github.com/Siniy-Vyacheslav/Site_For_Reading. Please, don't desert me)

Comment: The fact that your code is in another file is not the problem. I suspect that your script code is running before the html has been added to your page. As such, you'd be best to put your script tag as the last thing in the page (just before the closing </body> tag

Comment: As it is now. :)

Comment: Or may it depend from back-end language?

Comment: And yet i've got an error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous>. In line: document.getElementById('text').style.fontFamily = font;

Comment: Without seeing your site/environment it's hard to see what the problem is.

Comment: github.com/Siniy-Vyacheslav/Site_For_Reading This is my project in github. If it would be easier we can go to some social network. You'll get all that you need to help me with my problem. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. But my file uploader is working on my pc and other stuff in settings is not done yet because i needed to deal with Font-Family firstly. Without it couldn't do anything other anyway.